# Applying combn() function to data frame?

Tags: r, combinations

so I have a data frame containing certain type of data for different stocks, sample as followed:

```
Date     RY    TD     BNS...
10-01   2.98   2.29   1.91
10-02   2.96   2.61   2.15
10-03   2.96   2.59   2.09
...
```

What I want to do is to use combn() function to calculate the sum of the products of all possible combinations of 2 stocks. I know how to do it with single values using, for example:

```
df <- c(2.98, 2.29, 1.91)
sum(combn(df, 2, prod))
```

But since now I have a data frame with daily data for each symbol, how do I apply the above function and output the sum results as a data list corresponding to each date?

Thanks

Comment: I think it needs to be `apply(df, 1, ...)`: i.e. `apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x){sum(combn(x, 2, prod))})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Alistaire, apply can be easily used for this

```
apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) {
     sum(combn(x, 2, prod))
}
)
```

You could also use package **parallel** and use **mcapply*** functions to run it in multicore modes